# Keras Issues with dimensions of input and output layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am having trouble writing a network with Keras. This network must, given as input a set of points belonging to a circle, determine that circle. Basically, the network has as input an array of dimensions (num circles, num points, 2), representing a number "num points" of coordinates of a number "num circles" of circles, in 2 dimensions. The network must have as output a vector (num circles, 3), with the 2 coordinates of the center of the circle and the respective radius.
The network is:

```
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras import layers


x_train = array_of_circles  
# Input vector of shape (100, 1000, 2) i.e., 100 circles of 1000 points each

y_train = np.concatenate((array_of_centers, array_of_radius.reshape(-1,1)), axis=1)   
# Output: [x_center, y_center, radius]

# Define the neural network model
model = keras.Sequential([
        layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(num_points, 2)),
        layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
        layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
        layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
        layers.Dense(3)                                                               # Output layer with 3 units for x_center, y_center, and radius
])

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')

# Train the model
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=32)
```

I tried compiling the code and I got this message:

```
Incompatible shapes: [32,1000,3] vs. [32,3]
     [[{{node gradient_tape/mean_squared_error/BroadcastGradientArgs}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_6137]
```

How can I match the input and output shapes?

Comment: Hi! Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as I am not able to replicate your error. Thanks!

Comment: I edited the body of my question! To compile it you can use random arrays x_train and y_train but with the specified shapes, thanks!

Comment: i added some imports, but there is still insufficient information for a MRE as per @SimonDavid comment above.

Comment: for example `array_of_circles` is not defined.

Comment: Thank you both for the edits! What's the expected shape of `y_train`?

Comment: The shape of the two arrays are: 
array_of_circles-->((num_circles), num_poionts, 2)
array_of_radius-->((num, circles))
array_of_center-->((num_circles), 2)
y_train = np.concatenate((array_of_centers, array_of_radius.reshape(-1,1)), axis=1)

So basically, array of circles are points of circles, y_train is the 3 columns vector with x_Center, y_Center, radius, for each of the circle

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you looking for, but the following works for me without error:

```
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras import layers

x_train= np.zeros( (100, 1000, 2))
y_train = np.zeros((100, 1000, 3))

print(x_train.shape, y_train.shape)


# Define the neural network model
model = keras.Sequential(
    [
        layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(1000, 2)),
        layers.Dense(64, activation="relu"),
        layers.Dense(64, activation="relu"),
        layers.Dense(32, activation="relu"),
        layers.Dense(3),  # Output layer with 3 units for x_center, y_center, and radius
    ]
)

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="mean_squared_error")

# Train the model
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=32)
```

output:

```
(100, 1000, 2) (100, 1000, 3)
Epoch 1/10
4/4 [==============================] - 1s 21ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/10
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 20ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 3/10
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 20ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 4/10
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 20ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 5/10
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 19ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 6/10
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 19ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 7/10
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 19ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 8/10
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 19ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 9/10
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 19ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 10/10
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 19ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00
<keras.callbacks.History at 0x170fc8c5bb0>
```

Comment: With your code, everything works without error, but the model doesn't predict correctly. I think maybe that's a model problem